# Finding the value of a contour integral comprised of line segments

Tags: complex-analysis

I am attempting to work the following problem but I think am just forgetting a few things in order to answer it. The question asks to find the value of the integral of $(2z+1)dz$ on the contour $C$, comprised of line segments $C_1, C_2,...,C_{11}$ shown in the follwing figure

[image]

Now, I have not worked one quite like this, but I am assuming that I am to take the integral along each contour, so I will have a total of 11 of them that I will add together. What I do not quite understand what to do, I guess I have forgotten, is how to paramatize the function. Am I just t in for z(x+iy), making it $2t+1$ and then plugging in respective x and y values for each integration? Also, since the arrows are all pointing in the counter clockwise position, I am assuming that this is all addition. Please help.

Comment: Hint: If there was a $C_{12}$ from the end of $C_{11}$ to the beginning of $C_1$, then the integral would be $0$, since $2z+1$ is entire. So we can set the integral above equal to the integral from $0$ to the end of $C_{11}$ instead.

Comment: ok, so there is no need to take the integral of each line, just from the start of it to the finish?

Comment: Since this is a polynomial, the function is entire. Since it is entire, any integral of a closed contour will be equal to 0 and thus we have path indepence. So we can just take any other path to the same point (an easier one).

Comment: @Eoin, why are we integrating form 0 to 1? is it be because the x value for the beginning and ending is both 0, so we use the y?

Comment: Yeah. When you parametrize a path you are trying to make a mapping from some interval $[a,b]$ to every point on the path you are integrating, $C$. So here I chose $[0,1]$ with the function $z(t)=0+it$ because, since the $\Re(z)$ component of $z$ is 0 the whole time, it did not need a parametrization of $t$, and I could just focus on the values $\Im(z)$ took.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the comment I had just written. Let's Parametrize this integral. We wish to integrate the contour from $0$ to $i$. So our parametrization would be $z(t)=0+it$ where $t\in [0,1]$. Then to evaluate the integral we need only substitute as follows:
\begin{gather*}
\int_Cf(z)dz = \int_0^1f(z(t))z'(t)dt = \int_0^1 (2(it)+1)(i)dt\\
\int_0^1 (-2t+i) dt = \bigg[-t^2+it\bigg]\bigg|_0^1\\
=-1+i
\end{gather*}

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: thank you so much for clearing this up for me.

Comment: when you took the integral of (-2t+i), isnt that suppose to be -t^2 + it???

Comment: @cele Yep! haha

Comment: are you sure about this problem? After looking at this again, I really want to say to do it the other way, where I take the integral of C1 through C11 and add them up. When I asked my professor about this, he said that yes, this problem would be like a previous example that where we did add up each integral but to consider that if f(z) is analytic in the domain and on the contour, the integral is not depending on any particular contour. Is this what you mean when you say the function is entire, therefore does not require solving it this way?

Comment: @cele yes. The definition of entire is that it is analytic on all of $\mathbb{C}$. So the integral is not dependent on any particular contour. The only thing that should change is the sign depending on which direction you traverse the contour. Since they are path independent, a closed contour will result in the integral being $0$. So here we set the integral over $C_1...C_{11}$ + $C_{new}$ equal to 0 and then subtract. So your integral is equal to the ccw contour from $i$ to $0$ or, the cw contour from $0$ to $i$.